# How do I create a function that adds floats and integers and ignores strings?

Tags: python, string

This is basically it. I am starting to work with python and was flabbergasted with this task. I've just been seeing basic functions, and this seems over the top. Any suggestions?

I tried defining a function and an empty_set within it, and using something like for item in items, if item is a float or a string, empty_set.add(items), but this doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Comment: Post your best attempt. We don't even know how this data is presented, making it hard to suggest solutions. You likely want a for loop to iterate input values. Inside that, use a try/except clause with an attempted add inside it. adds that fail raise an exception and you can skip them.

Comment: Adding an int and a float is trivial. You are doing far more than this in your function if you have to extract the numbers from a string (or is it just a container?) in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Addition will typically raise a `ValueError` for invalid values. You can use that to your advantage by catching and ignoring that exception on each attempted add.

This example tries to be as liberal as possible, accepting anything that will add to a float and even attempting to change strings to floats before the add.

```
>>> def relaxed_sum(collection):
...     result = 0.0
...     for item in collection:
...             try:
...                     result += float(item)
...             except ValueError:
...                     pass
...     return result
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> relaxed_sum([1,99.99, "foo", "33"])
133.99
>>>
```